# Protobuf-Net Extention methods keeps throwing exception

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0, protobuf-net

I created a sample application in VS2010 with .Net 4 setting. I am trying out the ProtoBuf-Net Extention methods. However, Whenever, I try to call GetValue extention, It throws an exception saying

```
Method or operation is not implemented
```

StackTrace:

```
   at ProtoBuf.ExtensibleUtil.GetExtendedValues[TValue](IExtensible instance, Int32 tag, DataFormat format, Boolean singleton, Boolean allowDefinedTag)
   at ProtoBuf.Extensible.TryGetValue[TValue](IExtensible instance, Int32 tag, DataFormat format, Boolean allowDefinedTag, TValue& value)
   at ProtoBuf.Extensible.TryGetValue[TValue](IExtensible instance, Int32 tag, DataFormat format, TValue& value)
   at ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetValue[TValue](IExtensible instance, Int32 tag, DataFormat format)
   at ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetValue[TValue](IExtensible instance, Int32 tag)
   at PhoneBookData.PhoneBookSerializer.Serialize(PhoneBookProto phData) in E:\project\PhoneBook\Source\PhoneBookData\PhoneBookSerializer.cs:line 14
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\project\PhoneBook\Source\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 23
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Below is my Proto class with Extention support.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PhoneBookProto : Extensible
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired=true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public AddressProto Address { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4,IsRequired=true)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class AddressProto
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
}
```

What am i doing wrong. I have reference the latest protobuf version (561) available for download. Below is my code which keeps crashing.

```
Extensible.AppendValue<int>(phData, 5, 10);
Extensible.GetValue<int>(phData, 5);
```

**Edit**
the other older versions of protobuf also gives me the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. Extension data is one of the last pieces missing since the v2 re-write. As you can see it is [next on the roadmap](https://trello.com/board/protobuf-net-road-map/500900581f3aedaf06ded6ca), but pragmatically (time availability etc) I've had to prioritise the most common .NET scenarios first. And extension data simply isn't the most common usage. V1 has a fully working extension data API, and r280 (IIRC) is still available.

Once I get into this, I do not anticipate (having written it once before) it being a huge piece of work, so I hope it will be in the build pretty soon.

---

Edit: this should be available from r565 onwards

Comment: Thanks!. I tried r280 NET 3.0 version. It seems to be working.

Comment: If you could update the wiki pages on extension, that would be helpful to other's too

Comment: @SysAdmin please let me know whether it works / fails / something-in-between